# Magic.link React Native cannot import WebView from react-native

Tags: react-native

working on implementing magic.link using react-native but i get an error when importing Magic

```
import { Magic } from "@magic-sdk/react-native";
```

error:

```
Attempted import error: 'WebView' is not exported from 'react-native'.
```

I think its because of the sub dependency of react-native-webview  has been removed, but i did install it. npm install --save react-native-webview@^8.0.0 as the tutorial says? Stuck for a while now, not sure how to procede with Magic

https://magic.link/docs/login-methods/email/integration/react-native

This link was attached to the docs https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/373 . But don't know why it should not work, since the correct react-native-webview dependency was installed (8.0.0) or (^8.0.0, which is 8.2.1)

I installed the packages as the tutorial suggests

```
yarn add @magic-sdk/react-native

# Ensure the required `peerDependencies` are installed
yarn add react-native-webview@^8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
npm install --save @magic-sdk/react-native
```

then try to link it using npm react-native link

Comment: Yes, i installed the packages as the tutorial suggest I should. Updated the quesiton.